# How to divide a huge process into multiple steps in php?

Tags: php, database, execution-time, multi-step

I need to process an xml file and insert some data accordingly to my database. Since the XML file contains close to 10000 lines and there could be some thousand rows to insert to database I'm afraid my script will exceed `max execution time`.

I've seen some scripts that to prevent this, they divide the whole process into smaller steps and the script refreshes the page every few seconds and it continues whatever it's doing.

I just wonder how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using buffers:

```
set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo 'Starting... <br />';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {   
    echo $i . '<br />';

    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 

    sleep(1);
}
echo 'Finished. <br />';
```

I've put `set_time_limit(0)` (sets timeout to "infinite") just in case. The `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` is necessary for this to work. This worked on Firefox and Chrome, but not on IE. I'll update if I get it working on IE.

Update 1: You can also call the script via command line (CLI):

- Windows (cmd.exe): `php.exe -f \path\to\file.php`
- Unix (terminal): `php -f /path/to/file.php`

In these cases the buffers won't be necessary (they'll throw errors for there is no browser). In both cases you can start the process via PHP's `exec`, but you'll need to write the log in some file as it won't output to the browser.

Comment: Although I can not see how, this seems to work! I think I only have to adapt it to meet my needs.

Comment: Periodically it sends the buffer (stored output) to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded this with re-calling the php page with a continuing index variable before.

The steps were:

```
1. start the script with no querystring. it will insert 1000 rows for this time. 
   (insert_bulk.php)
2. recall the script with data start index 1001.
   (insert_bulk.php?start=1001)
3. when the data finishes, stop recalling the script.
```

This will prevent overflowing the max execution time, and tell you which part it's currently processing.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any more robust way of doing this?

Answer (score -2):

You could try to sleep() sometimes in your script.
Seems that it doesn't count as execution time ([for linux servers only](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#75557))

Comment: This won't help at all. Even if it doesn't count towards the execution time, it won't make the execution any shorter.